# OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.GL obsolete?

Tags: c#, opengl, compiler-errors, opentk

I just started using OpenTK but it said the GL class is obsolete. The error was **'OpenTK.Graphics.GL' is obsolete: 'Use OptnTK Graphics.OpenGL or one of the specific profiles instead.'**. I don't get what it's telling me to use instead. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

OpenTK comes with a standard (`OpenTK.dll`) and compatibility (`OpenTK.Compatibility.dll`) assembly. According to the [release notes](http://www.opentk.com/node/508/release) the compatibility assembly contains legacy-APIs (from the 0.x versions of TAO/OpenTK) which are removed from the standard assembly.

You are probably using the `OpenTK.Graphics` namespace (and the `GL` class from there) from the compatibility assembly and therefore getting this warning. If you are developing a new project you should remove the reference to the compatibility assembly and change your usings to `OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL` (or `OpenTK.Graphics.ES10`, `OpenTK.Graphics.ES11`, `OpenTK.Graphics.ES20` should you be targetting [OpenGL ES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES)).